# list comprehensions plus pattern matching

Tags: erlang, pattern-matching, list-comprehension

The problem I'm trying to solve is this: "find all elements of list L which is followed by the element with a value of X".

I was trying to do this using a list comprehension. However, I am now doubting it's possible. I understand how things are supposed to work in a simpler scenario, like this one

```
[some_transformation(X) || X <- [...], some_conditional(X)].
```

There's a filter on Xs which come out of a generator of Xs, and a transformation applied to those that pass.

I have a very slim hope, because the pattern-matching power of Erlang allows things like this:

```
[H1|[H2|T]] = [1,2,3,4].
```

, which binds H1 and H2. Is there some pattern that I can use inside a list comprehension to achieve the desired result?

When I naively try this, it obviously doesn't work:

```
78> [X||[H1|[H2|_]]=X <- [1,2,3,4]].
[]
```

Perhaps I should stop being lazy and want the magic of list comprehension and pattern-matching to do all the work for me? =P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could zip the list with the last element dropped with the tail of the list then use list comprehension:

```
1> List = [1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1].
[1,2,3,2,1,2,2,1,1,3,1]
2> X = 1.
1
3> Zipped = lists:zip(lists:droplast(List), tl(List)).
[{1,2},
 {2,3},
 {3,2},
 {2,1},
 {1,2},
 {2,2},
 {2,1},
 {1,1},
 {1,3},
 {3,1}]
4> [A || {A, B} <- Zipped, B == X].
[2,2,1,3]
```

This is inefficient though -- it creates a copy of the list (for `droplast`) and a new zipped list. You could use recursion like this to make this efficient:

```
-module(a).
-export([before/2]).

before(List, X) ->
  before(List, X, []).

before([A, X | Tail], X, Acc) ->
  before([X | Tail], X, [A | Acc]);
before([_ | Tail], X, Acc) ->
  before(Tail, X, Acc);
before([], _, Acc) ->
  lists:reverse(Acc).
```

```
1> c(a).
{ok,a}
2> a:before([1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1], 1).
[2,2,1,3]
```

Comment: Thanks! The first one, albeit inefficient, does show how it's possible to do what I want - but instead of attempting an esoteric generator, which won't work, your does 2 simple generators